# PHP how is a DOMNodeList constructed

Tags: php, domdocument

I realize DOMNodeList is meant to be a special type of "live" readonly reference list, but out of curiosity, how does it get constructed by other classes? For example, how does DOMNode "getBy*" functions construct a DOMNodeList?

```
//for example NOT with array of nodes
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<div></div><div></div>");
$list=new DOMNodeList([$doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)]);

echo $list->length;//doesn't work; empty; prints 0
```

Comment: If you check [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) `DOMNodeList` has only two method `count` and `item` that doesn't accept any input. So DOMNodeList hasn't any constructor for input. It instance with `DOMDocument`